# Is Visual Studio 2010's unit testing feature usable for native C++ code?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

It seems to be mainly tailored to .net code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only managed C++ (`/clr:safe`): [Unit Tests and C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243171.aspx)

You could use WinUnit (if you are not already): [Simplified Unit Testing for Native C++ Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc136757.aspx)

Comment: I'm familiar with WinUnit but was just hoping the slick in-built features would work with native code.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the slick attribute-driven features of managed test frameworks with native unit test frameworks. If you want a graphical runner which lets you select individual tests or fixtures within Visual Studio, grab the excellent, free [Visual Assert](http://www.visualassert.com/unit-testing-framework/). It supports both the cfix framework and (via cfix) a WinUnit compatibility mode. I've been happily using it for several months now in both 2008 and 2010.